# Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this. state.input')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, reactjs-flux

I am trying to read the key from a json file and display its value in a text field. User will enter the key value in the TextInput field. Following is the code I use. It throws "Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.input')" error after entering the text and pressing the submit button. I think there is some problem in binding/passing the value to the showMeaning() function. Please help.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {AppRegistry, StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, View} from 'react-native';

var english_german = 'english_german.json';
class Dictionary extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      input: '',
      output: ''
    };
  }

  showMeaning() {
    var meaning = this.state.input in english_german ? english_german[this.state.input] : "Not Found";
    this.setState({
      output: meaning
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.parent}>
        <Text>
          Type something in English:
        </Text>
        <TextInput value={this.state.input}
          onChangeText={(input) => this.setState({ input }) }
          onSubmitEditing = {this.showMeaning}
          />
        <Text style={styles.germanLabel}>
          Its German equivalent is:
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.germanWord}>
          {this.state.output}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
};

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  parent: {
    padding: 16
  },
  germanLabel: {
    marginTop: 20,
    fontWeight: 'bold'
  },
  germanWord: {
    marginTop: 15,
    fontSize: 30,
    fontStyle: 'italic'
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Dictionary', function () {
  return Dictionary;
})
```

Comment: var english_german = 'english_german.json';

`var english_german` has to be the content of your file, not the name itself.

Comment: @leo how do I import the content of the json file? I tried require() as well as import from. Both threw error messages that the module is not available.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `showMeaning` it is not bound to the correct context (`this`). You should [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) it or use arrow function which has lexical `this`, e.g.:

```
onSubmitEditing = {() => this.showMeaning()}
```

Comment: Or add this into your constructor `this.showMeaning = this.showMeaning.bind(this)`. It feels this is being said million times :D Take a look at https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Now it doesn't show the bidning error message. However it looks the content is not being loaded from the json. how do I import the content of the json file? I tried require() as well as 'import * from *'. Both threw error messages that the module is not available.

Answer (score 0):

As madox2 said, `showMeaning` is not correctly bound to `this`. This is a thorny issue with several possible solutions, the pros and cons of which are listed in [this medium post](https://medium.com/@housecor/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56). The cleanest one in my opinion is option 5, but that requires use of stage-2 features.